# Refraining from editing the questions of new users in order to educate them to write complete questions

Tags: discussion, edits, new-users

New users often post bad questions (the issue raised might be valid and interesting, but I am referring here to the **format of the post**).

They don't mention the language, put the wrong language tags (e.g. [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) instead of [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)), don't mention the error they get, don't specify the output they get and so on.

When these information become available (the language is obvious, they respond to a comment asking clarification) I always refrain from editing their question, instead I add a comment asking them to edit themselves the question to include the information and I explain why that is needed.

**E.g.** When they add the error they get or some clarifications in the comments alone. The edit I am referring to would add that information to the question.

I think this is important because by forcing them to do it themselves **we educate them to write good questions** (as opposed to have someone else edit their question). After all, all they have to do is click Edit and paste the information they already provided in comments. By doing it themselves it also puts a light on **the importance of having this information in the question**. If someone else edits their question after they post the comment, they might get the idea that posting a comment is enough, they don't have to do anything else.

Even if I post a comment asking them to edit the question themselves and explaining why it's important, some other user still goes on and edits the question.

So the question is: should we make this kinds of edits? Are my points valid? One downside of not editing the question is that the question remains *bad* for a longer time, possibility missing the opportunity of some answers. However I don't believe this shouldn't weight much because the gain of educating the user is greater on the long term and the question will surface back on the homepage again when it is edited eventually.

And if we should refrain from these edits, should we also educate the community on this?

---

*A little more clarification*: I am talking about edits to add information, not to spell-check, rephrase, or format the code.

For instance formatting the code for new users I think is a good thing because the markdown and copy-pasting code in the question can be confusing at first, even if for us it feels like second-nature. This would be  an example where learn by seeing at first is better then asking to do.

Comment: e.g. A post with just 'not working diagnostic`. After being asked they add the error message as a comment. The edit I'm referring is to add the error message in the question.

Comment: I think it is fine either way. If it is in a comment, then I ask them to edit their post and let them know that this information is much easier to read in the post itself and so that's where it belongs. If someone else wants to mess with editing in and formatting then that's fine by me. But I would still suggest leaving a comment to the OP about where it belongs. However, I think most people will probably get the hint fairly quickly after seeing there posts being edited.

Comment: It may be helpful, as a preventative best practice, to include an explicit encouragement to edit the question, using the handy `[edit]` magic link, in the initial request for clarification, e.g. "What did the error message actually say? Please [edit] this information into your post."

Comment: @IsaacMoses I didn't know about  the `[edit]` link. Thank you.

Comment: @bolov: re "e.g. A post with just 'not working diagnostic`. After being asked they add the error message as a comment. The edit I'm referring is to add the error message in the question." It would be really helpful if you edited your original question to include this clarification more clearly. ;)

Comment: Ironically this has become the target of itself as it appears crucial information to understanding my point is in the comments and need to be added to post itself. (I added it, hopefully it is clearer now).

Answer (score 10):

I disagree. Our first concern is the quality of content on the site. If we can see a way to improve a question, why not do it?

By editing, we can teach by example and show them what they need to correct, all while improving the overall quality of content on the site.

Comment: Even better would be editing plus an instructive comment, like "I've added the information in your comments to the question. If you have any additional information that would make this question clearer and easier to address, I encourage you to [edit] it into the post instead of commenting."

Comment: Be the change you wish to see in the world.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that you either have this information already in the question, or you do not. No site editor can add the text of the error the original asker was seeing, or specify the output the original question asker is getting, since they couldn't possibly know this information—so a significant part of the issue you're raising can't exist by definition.

That leaves poor formatting, unclear writing, and tagging things to the wrong tags. The latter we should definitely address correctly, as there are significant site issues for other uses if content is not appearing in the right places, and the questioner is of course much less likely to get a useful answer if their question is showing up only in the wrong tags.

Comment: I said and gave example: when the OP adds crucial information in the comments.

Comment: Ah, TLDcompletelyR phenomenon on my part perhaps. Although the wording of "After all, all they have to do is click Edit and paste the information they already provided in comments." is not entirely unambiguous.

Comment: Ah. Found more information about what you were referring to in your comments on your original question! :)